# Force latex to finish compiling regardless of error? (xelatex)

Tags: xetex, errors, compiling, python

I have a reoccurring problem.

I want to be able to force latex to finish compiling regardless of an error. I know that this error will occur several times in my script and it is a result of the pythontex package.

I use the pythontex package to import data into my report that I've manipulated in python. To use pythontex first you compile the tex document with latex (I use xelatex), then with pythontex, and then once again with latex. So in the command line I run:

```
xelatex mydoc.tex
pythontex mydoc.tex
xelatex mydoc.tex
```

The problem is, I want to be able to color code the values returned from python based on whether they are greater than or less than zero. However, the first time I compile my tex file with xelatex (or whatever), because pythontex hasn't been run yet, the \py{2} argument I'm passing my `colorme` function is empty. This throws an error, and the whole process grinds to a stop.

I will be creating more similar functions such as `colorme` so I am hoping there is an all encompassing solution that will help keep latex runnign despite the inevitable errors from empty arguments.

Is there anyway to force latex to finish compiling, so that I can at least run pythontex?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

%color things red!
\newcommand{\colorme}[1]{

    \ifnum\ifnum\numexpr 0 < #1
        \textcolor{black}{#1}
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1} 
    \fi

}

\begin{document}

\colorme{\py{2}}
\colorme{\py{-2}}
\colorme{2}
\colorme{\py{-2}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
xelatex -help
```

suggests

```
-interaction=STRING     set interaction mode (STRING=batchmode/nonstopmode/
                          scrollmode/errorstopmode)
```

you probably want `batchmode` but a possibly better alternative would be to fix your macro to accept empty arguments eg

```
  \ifnum\numexpr 0 < \ifx\valign#1\valign0 \else #1\fi\relax
```

will make `{}` be tested as `0` but still print as empty.

You definitely want to change `\ifnum\ifnum` to `\ifnum` in any case.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}

%color things red!
\newcommand{\colorme}[1]{%
    \ifnum\numexpr 0 < \ifx\valign#1\valign0 \else#1\fi\relax
        \textcolor{black}{#1}%
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\colorme{}
\colorme{2}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm, your fix to my macro doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting a `Incomplete \ifnum` error

Comment: when I call \colorme{}

Comment: @JoeDanger I added the updated code to the answer: you also had omitted `%` from ends of lines and had spurious blank lines in the definition (which case `\par` tokens in the definition)

Comment: It works great with `\colorme{}` but with `\colorme{\py{2}}` its failing with an `Missing number treated as zero` error. Maybe `\py{2}` is not treated as empty. Is there a way to figure this out and control for it so that the code compiles?

Comment: @JoeDanger I assumed pythontex (which I don't have) defines \py(2) to be something expandable (or your `\ifnum` test would never have worked?)